# Task.Factory.StartNew guaranteed execution sequence

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have 2 threads calling "Task.Factory.StartNew". Let's just say that one thread (ThreadA) is slightly ahead than the other (ThreadB).

... in thread A, invoked slightly ahead

```
Task.Run(() => {
  SomeMethodInThreadA();
});
```

... in thread B, invoked slightly later

```
Task.Run(() => {
  SomeMethodInThreadB();
});
```

Does the *TaskScheduler* guarantee that **SomeMethodInThreadA** gets executed first before **SomeMethodInThreadB**?

If not, how do I do this? Use Task.Factory.StartNew and pass in special TaskScheduler?

Also, besides guaranteeing that SomeMethodInThreadA gets processed first, I also want to make sure that **SomeMethodInThreadA** finishes first before executing **SomeMethodInThreadB**.

I have looked into using a [StaTaskScheduler](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Roslyn.Services.Test.Utilities/Threading/StaTaskScheduler.cs), but I am not sure if this is the solution.

**EDIT:**

Without giving out too much details/drama about the program I inherited, I guess what I am looking for is a custom TaskScheduler which:

1. Honors the sequence when the delegate is queued
2. Executes them serially
3. Do it in the same thread, similar to the StaTaskScheduler source code that I linked above

Comment: Don't use StartNew http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html unless you do actually use a different scheduler (which i probably wouldn't recommend)

Comment: Well, I kinda have to because I somehow need a special TaskScheduler, similar to what StaTaskScheduler is trying to do.

Comment: I feel like you're solving the *wrong* problem.

Comment: If that guarantee was there then all tasks would be serialized globally. That's identical with only one thread running tasks.

Comment: What about doing `{ SomeMethodInThreadA(); SomeMethodInThreadB(); }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Without giving out too much details/drama about the program I
>   inherited, I guess what I am looking for is a custom TaskScheduler
>   which:
>
> 1. Honors the sequence when the delegate is queued
> 2. Executes them serially
> 3. Do it in the same thread, similar to the StaTaskScheduler source code that I linked above

If that is all you want all you need to do is make a `BlockingCollection<Action>` then loop through the list on a dedicated thread.

```
public class BackgroundJobSchedueller
{
    readonly BlockingCollection<Action> _queue;
    readonly Thread _thread;

    public BackgroundJobSchedueller()
    {
        _queue = new BlockingCollection<Action>()
        _thread = new Thread(WorkThread)
        {
            IsBackground = true,
            Name = "Background Queue Processor"
        };
        _thread.Start();
    }

    public void StopSchedueller()
    {
        //Tell GetConsumingEnumerable() to let the user out of the foreach loop
        // once the collection is empty.
        _queue.CompleteAdding();

        //Wait for the foreach loop to finish processing.
        _thread.Join();
    }

    public void QueueJob(Action job)
    {
        _queue.Add(job);
    }

    void WorkThread()
    {
        foreach(var action in _queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            try
            {
                action();
            }
            catch
            {
                //Do something with the exception here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When there is no work to do the thread sleeps, blocked on the foreach, once you add a item to the queue it gets processed then goes back to sleep.

Comment: Oh dear, this works!, especially my delegates have the same signature!

Comment: Even if your methods did not have the same signanture you could still use it by wraping the method in a lambada `schedueller.QueueJob(() => SomeMethodWithParams(42))`

Answer (score 0):

> Does the TaskScheduler guarantee that SomeMethodInThreadA gets executed first before SomeMethodInThreadB?

No.

> If not, how do I do this?

have you second task be a continuation of your first task by using [ContinueWith](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith(v=vs.110).aspx)

Something like:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => {
    SomeMethodInThreadA();
});
```

Then later:

```
task.ContinueWith(t => {
    SomeOtherMethodInThreadA();
});
```

Comment: The 2 threads don't necessarily communicate with each other, so there is no way for me to get hold of that "task" variable.

Comment: @alpinescrambler: Of course you can. Plus it's existing in the parent thread not in thread A.

Comment: What I mean is, these 2 threads are written such that they are independent with each other. There is no facility to pass the "task" variable that you captured in your example.

Comment: @alpinescrambler Then you need to fix that.  A task can't be dependent on something that it's not allowed to know anything about.  You'll need to design your program such that the operation with the dependency accepts a `Task` to be a continuation of, or something along those lines.

Comment: @alpinescrambler: You don't have to pass anything from one thread to another. The parent that starts the first task is where `task` exists. You then add the continuation *in that same parent thread*. Thread A doesn't need to know anything about the task (and, in fact, there is no Thread B). If the two task are being created in different methods so that `task` would be out of scope, then just stick it in a member field.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodA())
                .ContinueWith(a =>
                {
                     MethodB();
                });

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey(false);

        }

        public static void MethodA()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello From method A {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }

        public static void MethodB()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            Console.WriteLine("Hello From method B {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Does the TaskScheduler guarantee that SomeMethodInThreadA gets
>   executed first before SomeMethodInThreadB?

Of course not.

> If not, how do I do this?

If the 2 threads are completely independent from each other and yet `SomeMethodInThreadB` must execute after `SomeMethodInThreadA` has finished you could use standard thread synchronization routines:

```
public static AutoResetEvent Wait = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

and then when starting the first task:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => 
{
    // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block.
    Wait.Reset();

    // Execute the first task
    SomeMethodInThreadA();

    // The first task has finished executing -> signal the second
    // thread which is probably waiting that it can start processing
    // the second task
    Wait.Set();
});
```

and then in the second thread wait to be signaled that the first method has finished executing:

```
Task.Run(() => 
{
    if (!Wait.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)))
    {
        // We have waited for too long the first task to execute - giving up
    }
    else
    {
        // The first task has finished executing - we can now
        // proceed with the second task
        SomeMethodInThreadB();
    }
});
```

Obviously it's up to you to define how long the second thread will wait for the first task to finish before giving up.